# Ionic scroll top sepcific element on viewdidenter

Tags: ionic4

Is there any way to scroll top in ionic specific element when a viewdidenter?

```
<ion-content nopadding>
    <div class="notes-main" *ngFor="let item of notesGroupDate">
      <h3 class="heading"*ngIf="today" #scrolltop>{{item[0]| date}}</h3>
      <div no-border *ngFor="let data of item[1]">
        <div class="notes-subject">{{data.field_subject}} {{data.field_assigned_to_class}}</div>
        <div class="notes">
          <div class="notes-data private" *ngIf="data.field_private_notes_title || data.field_private_notes">
            <div class="notes-icon" *ngIf="data.field_private_notes_title || data.field_private_notes">
              <ion-img src="../../assets/Diary_PersonalNote.svg"></ion-img>
            </div>
            <div class="notes-details">
              <div class="notes-title">{{data.field_private_notes_title}}</div>
              <div class="notes-description">{{data.field_private_notes}}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</ion-content>
```

I want to scroll top `<h3 class="heading"*ngIf="today" #scrolltop>{{item[0]| date}}</h3>` this element if condtion satisfy on ionviewdidenter.

Comment: ionViewDidEnter is run the first time as well. Just curious why you a specific about that event, sounds like you think it will only run after the page has been viewed once?

Comment: also your code as its written will contain multiple `#scrollTop` as its inside an `*ngFor`

Comment: as per my condition #scrolltop appear only one time.

Comment: @rtpHarry 
 I have a list of events for the entire month. I want to show the current day event always on top. so current day event scroll top.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this to scroll to the top of the page each time you go back to the page:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IonContent } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({...})
export class MyPage{
  @ViewChild(IonContent) content: IonContent;

  scrollToTop() {
    this.content.scrollToTop(400);
  }
  ionViewDidEnter(){
    this.scrollToTop();
  }
}
```

It sounds like that's what you are looking for, unless this is a simplified version of your real app, in which case we will need to use `scrollToPoint` and then write some code to get the y offset for that spot.